# how can i add a date filter that filters from all time

Tags: php, mysql, filter, searchbar

So i want to have a search bar where i can filter through everything by date how would i be able to do that?
This code currently just displays all the data from a mysql table in a panel but only from the current day so now i need a filter where i can search through the previous days.

```
<body style='background-color:grey;'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='head'>
        <h1 class='text-center'style='color:black'>Kennzahlen</h1>
      </div>
      <div class='row justify-content-center' style='color:black'>
        <?php
          #Alle Daten von HEUTE aufrufen und 2 Dimensionale array mit php bauen.
          $data =  [];
          $results = $con->query("SELECT systemname, identifier, value, date FROM kpi_log WHERE  CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST( curdate() AS DATE)");
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
            $data[$row['systemname']][$row['identifier']] = $row['value'];
          }
          #Schleife in Schleife und Werte auswerten
          foreach($data as $key => $d){
            echo '<div class="card bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header" style=background-color:dee2e6>
                      <li>Systemname: '.$key.'</li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body"style=background-color:dee2e6 style=color:red <div class="mt-4">
                      <li>Letzter Login: '.$d['last_login'].'</li>
                      <li>Aktive GPS Nutzer: '.(float)$d['active_gps'].'</li>
                      <li>Inaktive GPS Nutzer: '.(float)$d['inactive_gps'].'</li>
                      <li>Aktive App Benutzer: '.(float)$d['aktive_app_benutzer'].'</li>
                      <li>Inaktive App Benutzer: '.(float)$d['inaktive_app_benutzer'].'</li>
                      <li>Aktive Backend Benutzer: '.(float)$d['aktive_backend_benutzer'].'</li>
                      <li>Inaktive Backend Benutzer: '.(float)$d['inaktive_backend_benutzer'].'</li>
                    </div>
                  </div>';
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: 1. Add a form field for search where date is entered. 2. Change your MySQL query to look up by date, ie. change `WHERE CAST( curdate() AS DATE` to `WHERE date = :date`, make it a prepared query, and `->execute(['date' => $_GET['date'])`. 3. Not sure why you're doing the castings in the query, functions in `WHERE` prevent an index being used (and in a log data, assuming there's quite a bit, you definitely want one).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.